# Does Microsoft Authenticator require Azure AD?

Tags: c#, asp.net, authentication, azure-active-directory

My scenario is that I'm looking to implement [Microsoft Authenticator](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/account/authenticator) in my ASP.NET C# web application in order to provide 2FA.

All my user data is self contained within our SQL Server database.

Is it possible to utilise Microsoft Authenticator without also using a service such as [Azure Active Directory B2C](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/active-directory-b2c/)?

Alternatively we are thinking of utilising [Google](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/dotnet/guide/aaa_oauth#web_applications)'s offering or [Twilio](https://www.twilio.com/) however our client's IT resource seemed to think that it would be possible to use Microsoft Authenticator without Azure Directory.

Any guidance much appreciated.

Comment: I'm not sure how to answer this other than *yes*.  Almost *all* authenticators can be used without any server side auth framework.  Certainly can make it easier so you don't have to store your own token but otherwise it's pretty simple

Comment: Thanks Erik - Am I correct in saying it's a simple case of creating a [QR code](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/identity-enable-qrcodes?view=aspnetcore-2.2) and then for the user to add it as a [non Microsoft account](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure/active-directory/user-help/user-help-auth-app-add-non-ms-account)?

Comment: Something like that.  The QR Code is really just a picture representation of a number, so either way works (I tend to provide both.  The algorithms used aren't different even between platforms so the (QR) Code used use produce the same key on both Google and Microsoft Authenticators.

Comment: There are a lot of examples ([Here](https://medium.freecodecamp.org/how-to-set-up-two-factor-authentication-on-asp-net-core-using-google-authenticator-4b15d0698ec9)) on how it works.  If you're creating an asp.net-core application I believe it's built into it.

Comment: Many thanks Eric. That's been really useful.

Comment: Cool good luck!